# Convert SQL query into LINQ query in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

I would like to know how to convert the SQL query listed below into a LINQ query in VB:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT SUM(t.Amt) Tax, g.GenQuoteDetails_Id, g.lastTkdt, g.QuoteDt, g.BaseFareCurrency, g.BaseFareAmt, g.BaseDecPos, g.LowestorNUCFare, g.EquivCurrency, g.EquivAmt, g.EquivDecPos,g.TotCurrency,g.TotAmt,g.TotDecPos,fareinfo_id FROM GenQuoteDetails g
     INNER JOIN TaxData t ON t.TaxDataAry_Id = g.GenQuoteDetails_Id
     GROUP BY  g.GenQuoteDetails_Id, g.lastTkdt, g.QuoteDt, g.BaseFareCurrency, g.BaseFareAmt, g.BaseDecPos, g.LowestorNUCFare, g.EquivCurrency, g.EquivAmt, g.EquivDecPos, g.TotCurrency, g.TotAmt, g.TotDecPos, fareinfo_id) a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT p.PenFeeAry_Id, r.RsvnRules_Id, p.TkNonRef, fareinfo_id
     FROM PenFee p, RsvnRules R
     WHERE p.PenFeeAry_Id = r.RsvnRules_Id
     GROUP BY p.PenFeeAry_Id, r.RsvnRules_Id, p.TkNonRef,fareinfo_id) b
ON a.fareinfo_id = b.fareinfo_id
```

Comment: I'd suggest your best bet would be to create a view.

Comment: Hai Mr Brain Hooper,i won't use database connection to filter. i have converted xml to dataset. now i want to filter the table using Linq concept. do you know any best solution to filter the table??  is there any convertor for SQL Query to Linq??

Comment: I couldn't say. I'm just learning Linq-to-Sql myself, and creating views is how I did the difficult stuff.