# Convert SQL query into LINQ - DateDiff function

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, linq

My task is to convert the following SQL query into LINQ using Groupby, Orderby, Date function.

```
SELECT 
       sd.name, s.BuilderName,
       Min(Date) as MinDatetime, 
       Max(Date) as MaxDatetime, 
       datediff(day, min(Date), max(Date))/ cast (count(sd.jobRobosname) as float) 
FROM 
       [Data] sd  
JOIN Example s ON s.name= sd.Name
WHERE jobRobosjobid='NOT RUN' 
GROUP  BY sd.name, s.name
```

I have tried like,

```
(from record in _db.Data                              
join jobRobos in _db.Example on record.Name equals Example.Name
where record.jobRobos jobid != "NOT RUN"
  group jobRobos by new {record.Name,jobRobos .BuilderName} into r
select new
{
    jobRobos Name = r.Key.jobRobos Name,
    BuilderName = r.Key.BuilderName,
    MaxDate = r.Key.Min(r.Date),
    MinDate = r.Max(c => c.Date),
    Diff = r.Key.datediff(day, MinDate, MaxDate) / r.Key.Cast(Count(r.Key.jobRobos Name) as float)
}).ToList();
```

I have referred some of the similar questions here like:

- [How to convert SQL query into LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664610/how-to-convert-sql-query-into-linq)
- [Convert SQL query into linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701795/convert-sql-query-into-linq-to-entities)
- [Convert SQL query into LINQ query in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580740/convert-sql-query-into-linq-query-in-vb)
- [Translate SQL Query into LINQ Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204280/translate-sql-query-into-linq-query)

But could not find the solution.

Can anyone suggest me some ideas ?

Comment: Can you state the errors you are getting?

Comment: It is stating the error text as, `AnanymousType Error`

Comment: You have added tags for mySQL and SQL Server. Which are you using? If the latter then you can use `SqlMethods.DateDiffDay` - see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.sqlclient.sqlmethods.datediffday(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: your sql has error .. as you can not use `sd.spidername` .. it is not in groupby clause

Comment: Stanard comment to all such questions: LINQ isn't SQL and using it like that is a major smell. It isn't a replacement for SQL and neither are L2S or EF. ORMs are supposed to *map* entities to tables, not act as a replacement to SQL. Create *proper* entities and mappings and use LINQ to query the *entities*. Reporting-style queries shouldn't involve ORMs at all since *there aren't any objects/entities involved*

Answer (score 1):

With EF 6 this should work using [DbFunctions.DiffDays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.diffdays(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.DiffDays(System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D,System.Nullable%7BSystem.DateTime%7D)):

```
(from record in _db.Data                              
join spider in _db.Example on record.Name equals Example.Name
where record.spiderjobid != "NOT RUN"
  group spider by new {record.Name,spider.BuilderName} into r
select new
{
    Name = r.Key.Name,
    BuilderName = r.Key.BuilderName,
    MaxDate = r.Max(d => d.Date),
    MinDate = r.Min(d => d.Date),
    Diff = DbFunctions.DiffDays(r.Max(d => d.Date), r.Min(d => d.Date)) / r.Count(d => d.SpiderName)
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Here, the Diff value must be a Float . Then the cast operation should needed right?

Comment: Yes, point taken. However, casting to `float` may result in a LINQ to Entities error. If so then just bringing back the `DateDiff` and the `Count` separately and then do the cast as part of mapping the anonymous type brought back from the SQL to a model.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the exact error?